# How to get price range array in jquery array according to compare my amount

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my price range array of jQuery/Javascript.

```
var minAmtCriteria = [
    {
        min:0.00,
        max:300.00,
        min_amt:50.00

    },
    {
        min:300.00,
        max:1000.00,
        min_amt:50.00

    },
    {
        min:1001.00,
        max:3000.00,
        min_amt:100.00

    },
    {
        min:3001.00,
        max:10000.00,
        min_amt:125.00

    },
    {
        min:10000.00,
        min_amt:250.00

    },

];
```

How to get price range array according to compare my amount.

Suppose my amount is 50 then i want below range

```
{
min:0.00,
max:300.00,
min_amt:50.00
}
```

Suppose my amount is 3005 then i want below range

```
{
  min:3001.00,
  max:10000.00,
  min_amt:125.00
}
```

Please help

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: can you explain use of min and min_amt

Comment: I tried this but not success:
var myRangeArr = []; 
 for (var i = 0; i < minAmtCriteria.length; i++) {
  if(amt >= minAmtCriteria[i].min  && minAmtCriteria[i].max <= amt){
   myRangeArr = minAmtCriteria[i];
  }
 }
 console.log(myRangeArr);

Comment: switch the second part of the condition around and it should work `&& amt <= minAmtCriteria[i].max`

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) function of an array, which filters the objects in an array, like so:

```
var minAmtCriteria = [{
    min: 0.00,
    max: 300.00,
    min_amt: 50.00
}, {
    min: 300.00,
    max: 1000.00,
    min_amt: 50.00
}, {
    min: 1001.00,
    max: 3000.00,
    min_amt: 100.00
}, {
    min: 3001.00,
    max: 10000.00,
    min_amt: 125.00
}, {
    min: 10000.00,
    min_amt: 250.00
}];

var amount = 3005;

var range = $.grep(minAmtCriteria, function (n, i) {
    return n.min <= amount && (n.max == undefined || n.max >= amount);
});

console.log(range);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/x9vL12xk/1/)